# Where does a game actually start?

Tags: java, android

I just started creating games for Android and decided to begin by following [Retro Chicken](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTSRzzCcBtKMye3TfKM-k5A)'s tutorial.

What I just don't get is where the game actually starts to listen for commands?
Usually they'd have a function like `public void run ()` that is called.
The main is like :

```
game = new GamePanel(this);
setContentView(game);
```

And the constructor called of the main is :

```
public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this); // Inherits [Thread] class. Code posted

    player = new RectPlayer(new Rect(100,100,200,200), Color.rgb(255,0,0)); Class made by me. Has nothing special.
    playerPoint = new Point(150,150);
    // We ensure that THIS canvas will get the focus.
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

I surfed through some `super` calls, but still nothing

1. [MainThread.java](http://pastebin.com/TYhCiq9H)
2. [GamePanel.java](http://pastebin.com/iiibabW8)

   EDIT: I am interested in what calls the `run` function, where and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the block that actually starts the controller thread,

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

Since `class MainThread extends Thread`, calling the [`start`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) method of the Thread object will call the `run` method on a new Thread.

Now how does this method run?

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated
```

This is an override of the `implements SurfaceHolder.Callback` definition.

Your `game` object knows about the interface, because the constructor passes a reference of itself to the holder, itself, containing the interface to be called.

```
this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

The holder now has a reference to this class, and can call

```
callback.surfaceCreated();
```

Where `surfaceCreated` is interface method you implemented.

Now how did the surface get created?

[The `surfaceCreated` method is called when](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder)):

> This is called immediately after the surface is first created. Implementations of this should start up whatever rendering code they desire. Note that only one thread can ever draw into a Surface, so you should not draw into the Surface here if your normal rendering will be in another thread.

You started that process by calling finally calling `setContentView(game);` which inflated the surface.

Comment: So, basically, `surfaceCreated` is the one that starts all the methods. Thanks, That's what I was looking for!

Comment: `surfaceCreated` contains the block of code that starts the game thread, but that is only called because you `setContentView(game);`, if you were to create the game object, but never add it to the view, the Thread would never be started. You should not call that directly, but let the call hierarchy happen as it should, or you may end up with multiple rogue threads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the main thread gets startet, if its that what you want to know.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

I think you should specify your question a little bit.

Here is the callback method, that handles touches on the gamepanel.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    /* [event.getAction()] : returneaza un [int] care are o valoeare
        in functie de ce fel de touch e
     */
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But where is that function called ? That's what gets me troubled
And in `MainThread` class, there is a `public void run()` which basically starts the game, if I am not wrong. What calls that function?

Comment: The Thread Object internally calls the run() method when the start() method is invoked. 
Here for further understanding:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 0):

GamePanel class is SurfaceView, that provide drawing surface. You are adding a layer by `setContentView(game);`.

Now you need to start drawing. In drawing you need to erase and draw again if you need to change something on Paint Board(Surface View).

Now you need to call `draw (Canvas canvas)` again and again for the previous purpose. So you're using MainThread.

Look at your `run()` method of your MainThread, there is a infinite `while(true)` loop. By that loop your your GamePanel's `draw (Canvas canvas)` runs call at particular time duration.